# insert data to mysql table using jquery ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

i want to insert data to mysql table called vacancy using ajax.ajax successfully function alert run.but data don't save in table.and errors are occer.i am new for php and ajax

html code

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="postvaccode2.php" type="post">
         <fieldset>

             <!-- Form Name -->
             <legend>Post Vacancy</legend>

             <!-- Select Basic -->
             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-5">
                     <select id="cato" name="cato" class="form-control" id="cato">
                         <option value="IR">IT</option>
                         <option value="USA">Finance</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
             </div>

             <!-- Text input-->
             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-6">
                     <input id="comid" name="comid" type="text" placeholder="comid" class="form-control input-md" required="" >

                 </div>
             </div>

             <!-- Text input-->
             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-6">
                     <input id="loc" name="loc" type="text" placeholder="city or town" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                 </div>
             </div>

             <!-- Text input-->
             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input id="qul" name="qul" type="text" placeholder="qulification" class="form-control input-md">

                 </div>
             </div>

             <!-- Text input-->
             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input id="indate" name="indate" type="date" placeholder="indate" class="form-control input-md">

                 </div>
             </div>

             <!-- Text input-->
             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-4">
                     <input id="expdate" name="expdate" type="date" placeholder="expdate" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input id="gpa" name="gpa" type="text" placeholder="gpa" class="form-control input-md">

                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input id="des" name="des" type="text" placeholder="description" class="form-control input-md">

                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="title" class="form-control input-md">

                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input id="comname" name="comname" type="text" placeholder="name" class="form-control input-md">

                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input id="vacpost" name="vacpost" type="submit" class="form-control input-md">

                 </div>
             </div>

         </fieldset>
     </form>
```

script

```
    </script>

     <script>
         $('#vacpost').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "postvaccode2.php",
                 data:{id:$('#comid').val(),cato:$('#cato').val(),loc:$('#loc').val(),quli:$('#qul').val(),indate:$('#indate').val(),expdate:$('#expdate').val(),gpa:$('#gpa').val(),des:$('#des').val(),title:$('#title').val(),comname:$('#comname').val()},

                 success:function () {
                     alert('Sccessfuly Post the Job vacency');
                     location.reload(true);
                 }

             });
         });
     </script>
```

postvaccode2.php

```
    <?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","internship");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $cato=$_POST['cato'];
    $loc=$_POST['loc'];
    $quli=$_POST['quli'];
    $indate=$_POST['indate'];
    $expdate=$_POST['expdate'];
    $gpa=$_POST['gpa'];
    $des=$_POST['des'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $comname=$_POST['comname'];

    $sql="insert into vacancy(companyid,catogary,location,qulification,indate,expectgpa,description,title,expdate,companyname) values('$id','$cato','$loc','$quli','$indate','$gpa','$des','$title','$expdate','$comname',)";
    $conn->query($sql);
     ?>
```

Comment: `'$comname',` that trailing comma alone should have thrown you an error.

Comment: you also stand at having certain columns mispelled. Best you use `mysqli_error($conn)` and php's error reporting to debug all of this yourself.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving ?

Comment: 'Undefined index' id to comname...those are the errors